# C# Runtime Generated PictureBox Control

Tags: c#

I need your help, I'm using this code to generate multiple tabs in a TabControl each containing a PictureBox with a different JPG picture:

```
        foreach (var file in d.GetFiles("*.jpg"))
        {

            string title = file.Name + (TCFichiers.TabCount + 1).ToString();

            TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(title);

            TCFichiers.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);

            PictureBox i = new PictureBox();

            myTabPage.Controls.Add(i);
        }
```

I want to use a button that will rotate the image in the PictureBox of the selected tab however I can't figure out how to get access to the right PictureBox. How can I access only the picturebox  on the selected tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/78037-dynamically-create-multiple-picture-boxes/):

```
 PictureBox[] Shapes = new PictureBox[Num_Picbox];

                        for (int i = 0; i < Num_Picbox; i++)

                        {

                            Shapes[i] = new PictureBox();

                            Shapes[i].Name = "ItemNum_" + i.ToString();

                            Shapes[i].Location = new Point(label5.Left+1,label5.Top);

                            Shapes[i].Size = new Size(100, 100);

                            Shapes[i].BackColor = Color.Black;

                            Shapes[i].Image = (Bitmap)(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap));

                            Shapes[i].Visible = true;

                            this.Controls.Add(Shapes[i]);

                        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought a some sort of array could solve my problem. I still just a beginner at this...